# Weak-star topology on probability measures

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I'm currently starting to study Robust Statistics (based on Huber's book) and still somewhat struggling with the notion of weak-star topology $\tau_\ast$ on the space of probability measures.

Huber simply defines $\tau_\ast$ as the initial topology wrt the maps $$ \lbrace \mu \mapsto \int_X f d \mu \; \colon f \in C_b(X) \rbrace,$$ that is as the coarsest topology on the space $\mathcal{PM}(X)$ of probability measures on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ that makes all those functionals continuous. Here $X$ should be a Polish space and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ its Borel-$\sigma$-algebra.

Now I was curious why this is called weak-star-topology and what are the connections to the functional analytical / topological definition of the weak-star topology as the coarsest topology on the dual space $X^\ast$ of a topological vector $X$ space, that makes each evaluation functional $F_x: X^\ast \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F_x(f) = f(x)$ for each $x \in X$ continuous.

As the space $\mathcal{PM}(X)$ itself is not a vector space, it can't be a dual space itself, so we need to identify it as a subset of an appropriate vector space of measures which is the dual of some other space.

Based on one answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111245/what-is-the-weak-topology-on-a-set-of-probability-measures) and [this Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) my idea was to use the duality of $C_0(X)$ (the continuous functions vanishing at infinity) and the space $\mathcal{M}(X)$ of finite signed regular Borel measures on $X$. Then the weak-star-topology on $\mathcal{M}(X)$ would be the initial topology wrt to the family of maps
$$ \lbrace \mu \mapsto \int_X f d \mu \; \colon f \in C_0(X) \rbrace $$ and hence we would get the weak-star-topology on $\mathcal{PM}(X)$ as the induced subset topology. But this would then be the coarsest topology on $\mathcal{PM}(X)$ so that all the maps $F_f: \mathcal{PM}(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F_f(\mu) = \int_X f d \mu$ for $f \in C_0(X)$ are continuous.

So the difference to Huber's definition is that here we're only considering $C_0(X)$ functions whereas the definition above we have all $C_b(X)$ function, which should in general lead to a finer topology as $C_0(X) \subset C_b(X)$.

Now my question is, whether these two topologies are actually the same (for some reason I don't see) or how one might come to Hubers's definition with a similar functional analytical approach.

Comment: The space may not be a vector space in its own right, but it certainly seems like it would be an affine subspace (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) of the set of all measures on $X$, which *is* a vector space. Perhaps the weak* topology on the probability measures is just the restriction of the weak* topology of all measures on $X$, inherited as a subspace?

Comment: @RiversMcForge the space of probability measures is not an affine space but rather a convex cone.

Comment: @Michh good point, I stand corrected. Clearly they are different from the perspective of linear combinations. From the topological/subspace perspective, though, it seems like that distinction wouldn't be as relevant in terms of whether it could inherit the weak* topology from the larger vector space it lives in.

Comment: @RiversMcForge I agree that this is irrelevant for the purposes of this question, and one simply endows the space of probability measures with the subspace topology.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Of course the weak* topology on the space of probability measures is the inherited subset topology from some larger vector space of measures. My problem rather refers to what kind of larger space of measures and what type of Riesz representation theorem one needs to choose to come up with the bounded continuous functions $C_b(X)$ and not the vanishing functions $C_0(X)$

Comment: @Benny Can you not directly use the dual space $C_b(X)^*$, which will contain these probability measures as a subset? What makes that not an option? Or, are you asking for a nice characterization of $C_b(X)^*$?

Comment: @RiversMcForge That's also an option I already considered. However the dual $C_b(X)^\ast$ (which seems to be the space of all finitely additive signed bounded "measures") is less common than the result for $C_0(X)^\ast$ and I didn't find that much literature on this topic. That's why I tried avoiding this approach because I guess this would also mean that I would need to define the integral for only finitely additive "measures" instead of usual countably-additive measures

Comment: I don't think these topologies are the same. The measures $\mu_n$ that put mass 1 on $n$ seem to converge to the null measure in one topology, but not in the other.

Comment: @E-A That's a very good and easy example! Appreciate it