# The weak*-topology on a set of probability measures and convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denote the set of Borel probability measures on $(X,\mathscr{B}(X))$. By definition (I learnt it from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2116838/185631) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence)), a sequence of measures $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ in the weak* topology if and only if
$$\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu, \forall f\in C_0(X)$$

I wonder if this is equivalent to

$$\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A), \forall A \in \mathscr{B}(X).$$

If there are some mild condition can be added to $X$ (metrizability, separability, etc) under which this is true, please let me know. I am trying to find a counterexample in the case of $X=\mathbb R, [0,1]$,etc.

Comment: Let $\mu_n$ be the unit point mass at $1/n\in[0,1]$.  The sequence $\mu_n$ converges weak* to the point mass at $0$, but your conjecture is not verified by $A=(0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer guys, I rushed into it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a ***compact metrizable*** space. Then the following are ***equivalent***:

$$1.\ \int f\ d\mu_n\to \int f\ d\mu\text{ for all }f\in C(X)$$$$2.\ \limsup \mu_n(F)\leq \mu(F)\text{ for all }F\subseteq_{\text{closed}}X$$$$3.\ \liminf \mu_n(U)\geq \mu(U)\text{ for all }U\subseteq_{\text{open}}X$$$$4.\ \text{ For every }A\in\mathscr B(X)\text{ with }\mu\big(\text{boundary}(A)\big)=0\text{ we have }\lim\mu_n(A)= \mu(A).$$

**Proof of $(1)\implies (2)$:** Let $F$ be closed in $X$ and for $k\in\Bbb N$ let $U_k:=\{x\in X:d(x,F)<1/k\}$. Then, $U_k$ are open and decreses to $F$, so $\mu(U_k)\to \mu(F)$. By Uryshon Lemma choose $f_k\in C(X)$ with $0\leq f_k\leq 1$ and $f_k=1$ on $F$ with $f_k=0$ on $X\backslash U_k$. Then, $$\limsup \mu_n(F)\leq \limsup\int f_k\ d\mu_n=\int f_k\ d\mu\leq \mu(U_k)$$$$\implies\limsup\mu_n(F)\leq \mu(F). $$
**Proof of $(2)\implies (3)$:** Let $U$ be open in $X$. Then, $$\limsup \mu_n(X\backslash U)\leq \mu(X\backslash U)\implies \liminf\mu_n(U)\geq \mu(U). $$
**Proof of $(2)\implies (4)$:** Write, $\partial A=$ boundary of $A$, $A^o=$ interior of $A$, and $\overline A=$ closure of $A$. Let $\mu(\partial A)=0$. Then, $\mu(A^o)=\mu(A)=\mu(\overline A)$ and $\limsup\mu_n(\overline A)\leq \mu(\overline A)=\mu(A)$ and $\liminf \mu_n(A^o)\geq \mu(A^o)=\mu(A)$. So, we are done.

I do not write  $(4)\implies (1)$, but one can find the proof easily. For example, see  **Theorem 6.1 on page 40 of Probability measures on metric spaces written by K.R. Parthasarathy, Academic Press.**

Comment: If anyone interested I can write $(4)\implies (1)$.